# how to compare a password text with the bcrypt hashes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cryptography, bcrypt

I have a use case in my application that should prevent the user from choosing one of their last 3 passwords while resetting their password. I'm using Angular for the front end and Spring Boot for the back end . In my scenario, the user passwords are stored as bcrypt hash.

How can I compare the password entered by the user with the last 3 stored bcrypt passwords?

When I run the following code snipped example,

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder b = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    for(int i =0;i<10;i++) {
        System.out.println(b.encode("passw0rd"));

    }
```

it generates the following bcrypt hashes. each hash is different which is reasonable because when I check the `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder`, I can see the salt generated is random value.

```
$2a$10$tztZsPFZ.T.82Gl/VIuMt.RDjayTwuMLAkRkO9SB.rd92vHWKZmRm
$2a$10$yTHyWDmcCBq3OSPOxjj4TuW9qXYE31CU.fFlWxppii9AizL0lKMzO
$2a$10$Z6aVwg.FNq/2I4zmDjDOceT9ha0Ur/UKsCfdADLvNHiZpR7Sz53fC
$2a$10$yKDVeOUvfTQuTnCHGJp.LeURFcXK6JcHB6lrSgoX1pRjxXDoc8up.
$2a$10$ZuAL06GS7shHz.U/ywb2iuhv2Spubl7Xo4NZ7QOYw3cHWK7/7ZKcC
$2a$10$4T37YehBTmPWuN9j.ga2XeF9GHy6EWDhQS5Uc9bHvJTK8.xIm1coS
$2a$10$o/zxjGkArT7YdDkrk5Qer.oJbZAYpJW39iWAWFqbOhpTf3FmyfWRC
$2a$10$eo7yuuE2f7XqJL8Wjyz.F.xj78ltWuMS1P0O/I6X7iNPwdsWMVzu6
$2a$10$3ErH2GtZpYJGg1BhfgcO/uOt/L2wYg4RoO8.fNRam458WWdymdQLW
$2a$10$IksOJvL/a0ebl4R2/nbMQ.XmjNARIzNo8.aLXiTFs1Pxd06SsnOWa
```

**Spring security  configuration.**

```
  @Configuration
    @Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            try {
                authenticationManagerBuilder
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
            }
        }
       @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you can use `matches` method in BCryptPasswordEncoder, something like this:

```
b.matches("passw0rd", hash)
```

Comment: It is the solution, Can you help me to understand how spring security matches the hash password that is stored in database and the text password that is given by the user of course which will be different hash after encode !!!???

Answer (score 4):

Actually I found my answer .
I realized that I can use `matches` function in the class *org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder*.

```
System.out.println(b.matches("passw0rd", "$2a$10$tztZsPFZ.T.82Gl/VIuMt.RDjayTwuMLAkRkO9SB.rd92vHWKZmRm"));
```

Comment: It is the solution, Can you help me to understand how spring security matches the hash password that is stored in database and the text password that is given by the user of course which will be different hash after encode !!!???

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security just reads the salt from previously generated hash and rehashes the input password again with same salt. And it compares both final hashes and obviously it will be same.

Example:

Password: `test`

Hash: `$2a$10$nCgoWdqJwQs9prt7X5a/2eWLn88I8pon6iNat90u4rq4mHqtoPGQy`

Hash has 3 segments each separated by `$` symbol. `2a` is version of the Bcrypt, `10` is the total rounds and `nCgoWdqJwQs9prt7X5a/2e` is the salt.

So spring security takes  the password `test` and salt `nCgoWdqJwQs9prt7X5a/2e` and runs the hashing method. Obviously it generates the same hash as the password and salt matches.

Answer (score 1):

I had been facing a scenario where I had to verify my old password which is stored as bcrypted into DB in order to Change the password.
then I did it this way.

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder b = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            if(b.matches(oldNormalPassword, #Password)){ // code ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below :

```
  BCryptPasswordEncoder bc = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
     boolean passChecker = bc.matches("Normal Password Here", "Hashed Password Here");
```